# MqSQL exclude entries between

Tags: mysql

I have the query below. 
I aim to somehow exclude the entries between 4 and 14 and not show them.

```
SELECT code, register, data
    FROM code
    WHERE code
    BETWEEN 4
    AND 14
    ORDER BY code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `NOT` after column `code`.

```
SELECT code, register, data
    FROM code
    WHERE code NOT
    BETWEEN 4
    AND 14
    ORDER BY code;
```

Or you can also use 'NOT' before column `code`

```
SELECT code, register, data
    FROM code
    WHERE NOT code
    BETWEEN 4
    AND 14
    ORDER BY code;
```

Just [see this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da483/2)

Ref. [MySQL: *expr NOT BETWEEN min AND max*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-between)